# Classification with restrictions

Tags: scikit-learn

How should I best use scikit-learn for the following supervised classification problem (simplified), with binary features:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

train_data = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
                       [1, 0, 1, 1],
                       [0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=bool)
train_targets = np.array([0, 1, 2])

c = DecisionTreeClassifier()
c.fit(train_data, train_targets)

p = c.predict(np.array([1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=bool))
print(p)
# -> [1]
```

That works fine. However, suppose now that I know a priori that the presence of feature 0 excludes class 1. Can additional information of this kind be easily included in the classification process?

Currently, I'm just doing some (problem-specific and heuristic) postprocessing to adjust the resulting class. I could perhaps also manually preprocess and split the dataset into two according to the feature, and train two classifiers separately (but with K such features, this ends up in 2^K splitting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can additional information of this kind be easily included in the classification process?

Domain-specific hacks are left to the user. The easiest way to do this is to predict probabilities...

```
>>> prob = c.predict_proba(X)
```

and then rig the probabilities to get the right class out.

```
>>> invalid = (prob[:, 1] == 1) & (X[:, 0] == 1)
>>> prob[invalid, 1] = -np.inf
>>> pred = c.classes_[np.argmax(prob, axis=1)]
```

That's `-np.inf` instead of `0` so the `1` label doesn't come up as a result of tie-breaking vs. other zero-probability classes.